# Constrained optimization over a grid while maintaining proportions

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Suppose I have a user/item grid like this:

```
         item_1  item_2
user_1    v_11    v_12
user_2    v_21    v_22
user_3    v_31    v_32
```

Where each user/item pair has a value, as captured in the grid.  The goal is to assign *exactly one* item to each user, so as to maximize the sum of the values.

But also, "prior" proportions must be maintained.  For example, if in the past item_1 was assigned to 2 out of 3 users and item_2 was assigned to only 1 user, going forward we *either* have to have:

1. item_1 gets assigned to 2 out of 3 users (could be different users than in the past!), and item_2 gets assigned to the remaining user, OR
2. item_2 gets assigned to 2 out of 3 users, and item_1 gets assigned to the remaining user

Neither item may be assigned to *every* user.  This is what is meant by "maintaining" proportions.  How should I approach a problem like this analytically?  What about programmatically in Python?  Please let me know if I can clarify further.  Assume we know all the values (the v's).  Thank you.

Comment: I suggest creating a small data set (at least 3 items)  with the expected solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give this a try.

I assume we have the following data set with 10 items and 20 users:

```
----     23 SET i  items

item1 ,    item2 ,    item3 ,    item4 ,    item5 ,    item6 ,    item7 ,    item8 ,    item9 ,    item10


----     23 SET j  users

user1 ,    user2 ,    user3 ,    user4 ,    user5 ,    user6 ,    user7 ,    user8 ,    user9 ,    user10,    user11
user12,    user13,    user14,    user15,    user16,    user17,    user18,    user19,    user20


----     23 PARAMETER x0  initial allocations

             user1       user2       user3       user4       user5       user6       user7       user8       user9

item1                                                                                                            1
item2            1
item3                                                            1           1
item4                                                1                                   1
item6                                    1
item9                        1                                                                       1

     +      user10      user11      user12      user13      user14      user15      user16      user17      user18

item2                                                                        1                       1
item3                                                                                                            1
item6            1                       1
item7                                                                                    1
item8                                                            1
item10                       1                       1

     +      user19      user20

item5                        1
item7            1


----     23 PARAMETER n  sum initial allocations

item1  1,    item2  3,    item3  3,    item4  2,    item5  1,    item6  3,    item7  2,    item8  1,    item9  2
item10 2


----     23 PARAMETER v  values

             user1       user2       user3       user4       user5       user6       user7       user8       user9

item1        4.237       4.163       2.183       2.351       6.302       8.478       3.077       6.992       7.983
item2        4.720       2.059       3.828       1.419       4.047       2.639       6.812       6.047       7.930
item3        1.655       2.581       5.731       7.752       2.603       1.307       6.266       6.591       4.504
item4        2.818       1.046       3.427       5.499       2.362       2.568       3.976       3.852       3.899
item5        1.463       1.054       4.611       5.679       6.660       3.032       4.565       3.484       2.371
item6        1.915       4.455       3.917       2.729       2.011       6.369       5.603       1.406       8.048
item7        9.880       3.053       7.081       7.991       9.392       2.811       3.674       2.775       3.217
item8        8.612       6.514       9.784       1.242       2.687       1.784       5.864       2.142       7.606
item9        1.222       2.600       1.552       1.150       8.521       6.415       1.243       2.765       9.556
item10       9.395       4.139       1.075       9.540       6.147       4.003       9.854       7.898       1.991

     +      user10      user11      user12      user13      user14      user15      user16      user17      user18

item1        3.733       1.994       5.521       2.442       8.852       3.386       3.572       6.346       7.504
item2        3.680       6.950       7.802       6.647       3.555       1.778       1.923       6.771       5.908
item3        4.228       3.187       3.218       2.175       9.401       4.419       8.051       3.700       2.129
item4        9.676       9.942       4.329       4.356       7.948       4.570       9.218       2.076       7.619
item5        9.427       4.804       2.212       4.475       4.372       3.416       9.535       2.700       3.678
item6        9.512       6.368       6.466       4.263       6.347       7.119       5.559       2.433       6.912
item7        6.818       7.615       1.769       2.353       4.908       2.682       7.234       7.867       2.393
item8        2.019       5.395       8.160       5.428       5.802       1.096       5.895       5.060       9.778
item9        4.020       6.348       3.333       6.766       2.397       5.140       4.540       8.249       5.869
item10       9.953       6.223       2.498       6.790       4.099       9.211       9.101       1.146       4.318

     +      user19      user20

item1        6.654       5.174
item2        1.284       8.131
item3        7.740       1.623
item4        1.499       6.187
item5        1.671       4.612
item6        5.715       2.120
item7        4.504       7.259
item8        2.655       2.472
item9        4.516       6.020
item10       6.979       6.340

----     23 PARAMETER z0                   =       97.192  initial total value
```

The problem is to find a new assignment of items to users `x(i,j)` with:

- each user receives exactly one item.
- the total number of each item is a permutation of the original number of each item. So if we have 3 items and the totals were 1,2,3 then we can have now 3,2,1 (or any other permutation of 1,2,3).

For this we define two binary variables:

```
 x(i,j) = 1  if user j receives item i
          0  otherwise

 p(i,k) : a permuted identity matrix
```

We this we can develop the following Mixed Integer Programming (MIP) model:

[image]

This is a simple MIP model that can be solved with any MIP solver. The optimal solution looks like:

```
----     49 VARIABLE x.L  

             user1       user2       user3       user4       user5       user6       user7       user8       user9

item1                                                                        1                       1
item7            1                                               1
item8                        1           1
item9                                                                                                            1
item10                                               1                                   1

     +      user10      user11      user12      user13      user14      user15      user16      user17      user18

item2                                    1
item3                                                            1
item4                        1
item5                                                                                    1
item6            1
item8                                                                                                            1
item9                                                1                                               1
item10                                                                       1

     +      user19      user20

item2                        1
item3            1


----     49 VARIABLE z.L                   =      176.058  

----     54 PARAMETER sumitems  sum new allocations

item1  2,    item2  2,    item3  2,    item4  1,    item5  1,    item6  1,    item7  2,    item8  3,    item9  3
item10 3
```

The last vector `sumitems` is a permutation of the vector `n` of our data set.

We see the objective value of this optimal solution is 176.058 which is much better than the value of our initial (random) data set (97.192).

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer!  This is very helpful.  I haven't done MIP before.  Can you recommend any easy-to-use MIP solvers?

Comment: For Python, you may want to look at CVXPY or PuLP.

Comment: Thanks!  I will look into those options.